# Ajax request for login not working using $.post() method in jquery

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I have a login form i want to send username password to servlet and returning response from there but my username and password is not even going to servlet i have searched a lot but not getting anything please help me out ..
my code is given belo :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".mloginform").submit(function () {
        var uName = $("#usernameInputField").val();
        var passwd = $("#passwordInputField").val();

        $.post("/LoginServlet", {
            username: uName,
            password: passwd
        }, function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                alert("hello");
            }
        }, 'json');

        return false;
    });
});     
</script>
```

Inside LoginServlet doPost method:

```
String userName=request.getParameter("username");
String passwd=request.getParameter("password");

Gson gSon=new Gson();

Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();

data.put("success", true);

JsonObject myJson=new JsonObject();
myJson.add("data", gSon.toJsonTree(data));
response.setContentType("application/json");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.write(myJson.toString());
```

**where I am wrong.**

Comment: can you show us what error you are getting?

Comment: actually nothing i am getting ...nothing happening after clicking submit button if i am writing some alert than it is showing but data is not going to servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(document).ready(function () {

var uName = $("#usernameInputField").val();

var passwd = $("#passwordInputField").val();

var params={username:uName,password:passwd};

```
$.ajax({
    url : "LoginServlet",
    type : "post",                      
    cache : false,
    async : false,          
    dataType : "json",
    data : params,
    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success : function(data) {
                  alert("hello");
            }
       });
```

});